# Swap in C - Printing

Tags: c

I just implemented my swap function but it does not print anything. Do you know why does the line printf does not execute?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int swap(int x, int y) {
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("%d, x is",x);
    scanf("%d", &y);

    int temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
    printf("After Swapping: x = %d, y = %d", x, y);
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    swap(6,5);
}
```

Comment: Why you need to scan `x` and `y`?

Comment: The two `scanf` statements overwrite the arguments that were passed to the function.

Comment: What does not print? There are two `printf` lines and they both output what the program tells them to.

Answer (score 2):

You should not take user input inside the `swap` function. Its purpose should be to swap two integers only. You can move the `scanf` statements to `main` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int swap(int x, int y){
    int temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
    printf("After Swapping in swap function: x = %d, y = %d", x, y);
    return 0;
}

int main(void){
    int x, y;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("%d, x is", x);
    scanf("%d", &y);
    printf("%d, y is", y);
    swap(x, y);
    printf("After Swapping in main function: x = %d, y = %d", x, y);
}
```

But the above code has a major issue. Though the `swap` function prints the integers passed as they are swapped but the fact is `x` and `y` in the `main` remains unaffected.

In this case to make it work, using pointers would be helpful

```
void swap(int *ptrx, int *ptry){
    int temp = *ptrx;
    *ptrx = *ptry;
    *ptry = temp;
}
```

In the `main` function call the `swap` as `swap(&x, &y);`

Comment: @machine_1; Oops! Thanks a lot. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for swapping.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap(int x, int y)
{
    int z;
    z = x;
    x = y;
    y = z;
    printf("After Swapping: x = %d, y = %d", x, y);        
}
int main()
{
    swap(6,5);
    return 0;
}
```

And I don't understand why you need to scan x & y

Comment: Instead of having an `int` as return type in `swap()`, `void` can be used. The function is just returning `0` which is not of any use.